# Priority Queue of HashMaps in Scala

Tags: scala, hashmap, priority-queue

I'm trying to update the value of an element of my Priority Queue of HashMaps put with no success. Here's is how I'm doing:

```
def HashMapOrdering = new Ordering[HashMap[Int,Int]] {

  def compare(a : HashMap[Int,Int], b : HashMap[Int,Int]) = b.valuesIterator.next().compare(a.valuesIterator.next())

}

def main(args: Array[String]) {

  var seeds = PriorityQueue[HashMap[Int, Int]]()(HashMapOrdering)
  seeds.enqueue(HashMap(4 -> 4), HashMap(234 -> 5), HashMap(78 -> 6), HashMap(89 -> 1))

  seeds.find(x => x.get(89) == 1) match {

    case Some(hashMap: HashMap[Int, Int]) => hashMap.remove(77); hashMap.put(77,32)
    case None => println("Not found")

  }

}
```

Unfortunately, I always got the "Not found" message. Any ideias on what am I doing wrong or how to update the hash's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you've got a type mismatch. If you look the definition of `get` function, you'll see the following (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap):

```
def get(key: A): Option[B]
```

That means, that it returns value in your case typed as `Option[Int]`. So wrap your right condition argument in an `Option` monad:

```
seeds.find(x => x.get(89) == Some(1)) match {
    case Some(hashMap: HashMap[Int, Int]) => {
        hashMap.remove(77)
        hashMap.put(77,32)
    }
    case None => println("Not found")
}
```

Works as expected.

P.S. Forgot about your question about updating: you can use an `update` function instead of using `remove` and `put`: `hashMap.update(77, 32)`